# Call an overloaded method based on type without checking the type - c#

Tags: c#, methods

I have a class called `BasePaymentTransactionData`and several classes that inherit from it. I need to map data into an instance of this class I call `transaction`. The issue is I have to check if the transaction is a specific type and then call the associated overloaded function

This is my code:

```
class BasePaymentTransactionData { }

class CreditCardPrimaryRequestData : BasePaymentTransactionData { }

class transaction
{
    CreditCardPrimaryRequestData Map(CreditCardPrimaryRequestData transaction)
    {
         return transaction;
    }

    private BasePaymentTransactionData MapTransactionObject(BasePaymentTransactionData transaction, NameValueCollection parameters, string transactionType, string paymentMethod)
    {
        //BasePaymentMapping

        //Specific Mapping
        if (transaction is CreditCardPrimaryRequestData)
            transaction = Map(transaction as CreditCardPrimaryRequestData);

        // many more derived types ...

        return transaction;
    }
}
```

I was hoping it'd be possible to do something like

```
transaction = Map(transaction)
```

And the code would discern it's type and send it to the correct method. Is there any way to do this, or is the above the best I can do?

Also, I know it'd be preferable to just make an interface, and make a virtual Map() method, and just call that, but unfortunately I am unable to do that since I'm working with a lot of code that's framework level and wasn't designed by me

Comment: Do you have a Map function for each type?

Comment: Maybe generics?

Comment: Where is `Map` defined?

Comment: Try this: `private BasePaymentTransactionData MapTransactionObject(dynamic transaction, ...etc...) { Map(transaction); }` `dynamic` has scary powers of runtime overload resolution which I don't fully comprehend. Give it a shot. And define `Map(Object o) {...}` to catch anything there's no overload for.

Comment: @DStanley they're defined in separate methods in the same class as MapTransactionObject

Comment: dynamic is not all that magical. it just tells the compiler "I could be anything" so it skips all type checking during compilation. Then at runtime if the sig of your usage does not match the actual thing in memory...BOOM. Any overload resolution is still happening as normal based on the memory layout of the object which is determined by the actual type definition as per normal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DLR dynamic dispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx) feature:

```
private BasePaymentTransactionData MapTransactionObject(BasePaymentTransactionData transaction, NameValueCollection parameters, string transactionType, string paymentMethod)
{
    transaction = Map((dynamic)transaction);
    return transaction;
}
```

But make sure in addition to the specific `Map` overloads you also have something like this, otherwise you'll get an exception:

```
BasePaymentTransactionData Map(BasePaymentTransactionData t)
{
    return t;
}
```

A better type safe way would be to implement double dispatch ([Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)), but it would require more coding.